# I want to display row number with sequence

Tags: sql, database, oracle, report

I am done with my SQL query except row number. I want to display row number
For example

```
  | # | VENDOR NAME  | VENDOR BALANCE |
  +---+--------------+----------------+
  | 1 | VendorName_1 |     Balance1   |
  | 2 | VendorName_2 |     Balance2   |
  | 3 | VendorName_3 |     Balance3   |
  | 4 | VendorName_4 |     Balance4   |
```

here is my query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ( SELECT xsl.VENDOR_NAME
               , nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) Balance
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) ORDER BY  nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0)) rank_max 
        FROM xxng_supp_ledger xsl) 
 ORDER BY rank_max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT xsl.VENDOR_NAME
       , nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) Balance
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  (nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0)) desc) rank_max 
FROM xxng_supp_ledger xsl
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca46161c1b8088c5d222bc7d69ca4ee3)

This will order it by balance value from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function in the outer query as following:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rank_max) AS RN, T.* FROM (
        SELECT
          xsl.VENDOR_NAME, 
           nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) Balance
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) ORDER BY  nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0)) rank_max 
        FROM xxng_supp_ledger xsl
      ) T
      ORDER BY rank_max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
    ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @Mukeem I already tried this one also but not getting my requirement.

Comment: This is simply copied from https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/